# ProxyPass a URL to different port internally

Tags: apache

I've got the following URL.

```
https://helloworld.com/api/v1/en/user/register
```

And I'd like to redirect it to different port internally since my api service is running on different port and apache is running on port 80.

I'm doing like this in the apache2 conf but it doesn't work.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass ^/(api/v0.9/../.+) http://0.0.0.0:5000/$1
ProxyPassReverse $/(api/v0.9/../.+) http://0.0.0.0:5000/$1
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What is that mean to be? `v0.9/..` And what does "it doesn't work" actually mean? Also the `0.0.0.0` looks wrong... And last the leading dollar sign (`$`) in the `ProxyPassReverse` command is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this:

```
ProxyRequests Off 
ProxyPreserveHost On 
ProxyPass "/api/v1/" "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/" 
ProxyPassReverse "/api/v1/" "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/"
```

Comment: The target service may not be listening on the localhost interface.

Comment: Well, you know where it _is_ listening, we can't know that. Just change the host then. But you have to make a request to some specific target.

Comment: @arkascha, Hi, sorry for confusion. I've created a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562942/apache2-rewrite-proxypass-working-together