# Apache2 Rewrite + ProxyPass working together

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have apache web server running at port 80 and flask application at port 5000.

I need to process the following URLs and point to their ports accordingly.

```
http://hello_world.com/api/v1/en/user/register
http://hello_world.com/api/docs/
http://hello_world.com
```

What I need to do is

If the URL is `http://hello_world.com`, point it to my code_igniter router at index.php.

If the URL is `http://hello_world.com/api/docs/`, do not point to code_igniter, access straight to that folder.

If the URL is `http://hello_world.com/api/v1/en/user/register`, point it to my flask application at port 5000.

I have the following conf file. However, I kept getting 404 error when I tried to ProxyPass to port 5000.

```
File does not exist: /var/www/api/v1
```

However, my flask application router is supposed to route that /api/v1/... URI.

My conf looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@hello_world.com
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Rewrite for Code Igniter if the URI doesn't start with /api/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/(.+)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|fonts|assets|uploads|images)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# ProxyPass if the URI is /api/v1/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass ^/api/v1/(.+)$ http://localhost:5000/api/v1/$1
    ProxyPassReverse ^/api/v1/(.+)$ http://localhost:5000/api/v1/$1

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

...

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What is the `$1` in  `RewriteCond $1 !^/api/(.+)$` meant to be?

Comment: @arkascha it's %{REQUEST_URI}

Comment: How should that be? Why don't you put `%{REQUEST_URI}` in there?

Comment: @arkascha, i'd tried with %{REQUEST_URI}. however, it still isn't working. i'll update the question.

Comment: And _if_ that `$1` really resolves to `%{REQUEST_URI}` for you ( I have no idea how it should, but anyway...), then the second pattern `^(index\.php|robots\.txt|fonts|assets|uploads|images)` will never match anything. You forgot the leading slashes (`/`). However it is not required anyway, since those are existing files or folders, I assume.

Comment: @arkascha, I've made changes. What I need is if REQUEST_URI doesn't match with /api/ AND the `^(index\.php|robots\.txt|fonts|assets|uploads|images)`, redirect to index.php. Otherwise do ProxyPass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99527/discussion-between-moeseth-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy definitions are semantically wrong. Try that definition instead:

```
ProxyRequests Off 
ProxyPreserveHost On 
ProxyPass "/api/v1/" "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/" 
ProxyPassReverse "/api/v1/" "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/"
```